# XPath - displaying attributes

Tags: php, xpath

I have a following script:

```
<?php
    $str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <ROOT>
                <ITEMS>
                    <BOOK>
                        <TITLE>Name 1</TITLE>
                        <AUTHOR>Author</AUTHOR>
                        <CATEGORY id="1">NOVEL</CATEGORY>
                    </BOOK>
                    <BOOK>
                        <TITLE>Name 2</TITLE>
                        <AUTHOR>Author</AUTHOR>
                        <CATEGORY id="2">MANUAL</CATEGORY>
                    </BOOK>
                </ITEMS>
            </ROOT>';

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
    $category = $xml->xpath("/ROOT/ITEMS/BOOK/CATEGORY/text()");
    print_r($category);
?>
```

I want to select all the categiries in xpath.

I tried also:

```
$category = $xml->xpath("/ROOT/ITEMS/BOOK/CATEGORY");
```

But my output is:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 2 ) ) )
```

I don't want this output. I want to display NOVEL and MANUAL. I don't understand it, because I didn't use attribute command in xpath and I got it.

How to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: The output you're getting is exactly what I'd expect from `print_r($category);` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php - you need to iterate over the object rather than just spaff a "human readable" version to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I  have own solution. After few hours I have it! Thanks to your link in your answer. I read the examples and found how to get the right values.

```
<?php
    $str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <ROOT>
                <ITEMS>
                    <BOOK>
                        <TITLE>Name 1</TITLE>
                        <AUTHOR>Author</AUTHOR>
                        <CATEGORY id="1">NOVEL</CATEGORY>
                    </BOOK>
                    <BOOK>
                        <TITLE>Name 2</TITLE>
                        <AUTHOR>Author</AUTHOR>
                        <CATEGORY id="2">MANUAL</CATEGORY>
                    </BOOK>
                </ITEMS>
            </ROOT>';

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
    $category = $xml->xpath("/ROOT/ITEMS/BOOK/CATEGORY/text()");
    while(list( , $node) = each($category)) {
        echo $node."<BR />";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use xpath return arrays is an array of SimpleXMLElement Objects (http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), so they have their own structures. Somehow, you can iterate over this array and get all node values like this:

```
    <?php
        $str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <ROOT>
                    <ITEMS>
                        <BOOK>
                            <TITLE>Name 1</TITLE>
                            <AUTHOR>Author</AUTHOR>
                            <CATEGORY id="1">NOVEL</CATEGORY>
                        </BOOK>
                        <BOOK>
                            <TITLE>Name 2</TITLE>
                            <AUTHOR>Author</AUTHOR>
                            <CATEGORY id="2">MANUAL</CATEGORY>
                        </BOOK>
                    </ITEMS>
                </ROOT>';

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
        $categories = $xml->xpath("/ROOT/ITEMS/BOOK/CATEGORY/text()");
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            echo "$category\n";
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this makes nothing. No categories are shown.